# Automating HBase Online Merges

Tags: hbase

Long story short; I have an HBase database that divided into a huge number of small regions. I'm trying to merge them into larger regions, as the huge number of regions is drastically slowing performance.

I'm looking for a simple way to automate the merges; I thought the simplest way would be trying to use the REST API to automate searching for neighboring regions and attempt online merges.

I'm having trouble finding examples of how to do this, though. Is there a proper REST endpoint that can do this?

If it makes a difference, there is a Cloudera 5x interface to the cluster.